# ssh connect to host remoteIP port 22 connection refused

Tags: 12.04

```
sudo netstat -pant | fgrep :22
```

[image]

```
apt-cache policy openssh-server
```

[image]

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/859677/edit), and add the output on your virtual machine of both `sudo netstat -pant | fgrep :22` and `apt-cache policy openssh-server`. When you paste each result into the question, select the text you just pasted and press the `{}` button so that it's formatted properly.

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting.